# Firestore on Firebase is not sync on Google Cloud?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ttl

does anyone know how to make the firestore on Google Cloud be up-to-date with Firestore on Firebase?

I have tried first time using "Time-to-live" TTL on Google Cloud. when I create the policy to auto delete documents on firestore, I see there are still some options of collections that I deleted few days ago on my Firebase project, and the new collections did not appear.

So I can not set the TTL for the documents of new collections.

These are collections on my Firebase:
[image]

And here is what I have on Google Cloud:
[image]

As you can see from my Firebase, The collection of "Ads" should no longer exist, but the collection of "messages" should be there on the Firestore of Google Cloud instead.

Do you have any solutions for me? I appreciate it.

Comment: Can you provide screenshots of your console and explain what is not in sync?

Comment: Hi, I have added the pictures as above. Can I still have your help ?

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the documentation on [managing data retention with TTL policies](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/ttl)

> - Deletion through TTL is not instant and expired documents will continue to appear until the TTL process actually deletes them.
> - Data will typically be deleted after 72 hours after its expiration date. TTL also does not necessarily delete documents at the same time as their expiration.
> - If you require data deletion to be done transactionally, perform the deletions using a client library.
> - TTL deletions are treated with a lower priority to minimize impact on other database activities.

Basically, using TTL will not instantly remove the collection on Google Cloud Console but it is applied on Firestore Database once TTL policy is applied.